# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler' in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In windows phone application I want to add a button dynamically like below:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Content = tb_groupname.Text;
btn.Width = 200;
btn.Height = 200;
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);//Click event
```

But when I add click event on my button I am getting below error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler'
```

And below is the click event method of button:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textbox1.text = "ABC"; // For Example
}
```

I don't understand why its getting this error.
Kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The signature of your event handler is wrong.

It should be:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

And the [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx) event assignment should be changed to:

```
btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);//Click event
```

Comment: it gets me another error `No overload for 'btn_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'`

Comment: Did you change the `Click` assignment too?

Comment: Click assignment should point to [RoutedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `RoutedEventHandler` (found on the `System.Windows` assembly).

In your case, you should be able to change `btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);` with `btn.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);`; and then change the `EventArgs` ob btn_Click to `RoutedEventArgs`.

Make sure you add a reference to the `System.Windows` assembly or it won't compile!

Looking at the MSDN, I got this:

> The RoutedEventHandler delegate is used for any routed event that does
>   not report event-specific information in the event data. There are
>   many such routed events; prominent examples include Click and Loaded.
>
> The most noteworthy difference between writing a handler for a routed
>   event as opposed to a general common language runtime (CLR) event is
>   that the sender of the event (the element where the handler is
>   attached and invoked) cannot be considered to necessarily be the
>   source of the event. The source is reported as a property in the event
>   data (Source). A difference between sender and Source is the result of
>   the event being routed to different elements, during the traversal of
>   the routed event through an element tree.

Link to the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Button Click is Routed Event as mentioned by Patrick Hofman.

You can even shorten if don't want new event by  just writing
btn.Click += btn_Click;